# NFS: Why "sudo mount -a”cannot exit?

Tags: nfs

I installed NFS according to http://kb.prohma.org/index.php?title=Auto-mount_by_NFS. However, when setting up the client PC, and enter the mount command `sudo mount -a` the mount command hangs and I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit.

What's wrong? How can I find out more information about the mount for debugging?

```
$ showmount -e 192.168.1.252
Export list for 192.168.1.252:
/volume1/folder1 192.168.1.18/29
/volume1/folder2 192.168.1.18/29
/volume1/folder3 192.168.1.18/29
/volume1/homes 192.168.1.18/29
```

Comment: What does `showmount -e 192.168.x.x` say (replace the IP with the actual IP of the server)?